# spark-scala: download a list of URLs from a particular column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, wget

I have `CSV` file which contains details of all the candidates who have applied for a particular positions.

Sample Data: (notice that all the resume URL are of different file types-pdf,docx,doc)

```
Name    age Resume_file
A1      20  http://resumeOfcandidateA1.pdf
A2      20  http://resumeOfcandidateA2.docx
```

I wish to download the contents of resume URL given in 3rd Column into my table.

I tried using `“wget” + “pdftotext”` command to download the list of resumes but that did not help as for each URL it would create a different file in my cluster (outside the table) and linking it to the rest of the table was not possible due to lack of a unique criteria.

I even tried using `scala.io.Source`, but this required  mentioning the link explicitly each time to download the contents and this too was outside the table.

Comment: I trust that you're not proposing to use age as a way to compare candidates in the US ;)

Comment: Your question is not at all clear in either what exactly you want to do and what's failing in your current approach. Please edit. Having said that, you need to get the content of each file according to its MIME type, also taking into account the encoding. You will need to create a method/function that will take the URL, then return the text content (I assume). Spark will handle that just fine. You build an RDD (or DataFrame) of your data and apply map to the information in the Resume_file column, giving it your magic function.

Comment: edited my question.

Comment: @Phasmid would you be able to guide me with the scala -UDF, as i am not able find anything that takes the column data implicitly.

Comment: Are you still stuck on this?

Comment: My issue has partially been resolved. I have managed to download the resume files along with proper file extensin(.pdf/ .docx/ .doc) into a particular folder, also managed to extract the text content from these files using apache tika and storing the .txt file in a folder. Now the second part remains which would comprise of joining the folder (which contains all the .txt files)  to the table. --> I have added my code below as part of answer. (apache tika program not added here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Answer: Downloaded the text file to a particular location with proper extension and after giving the file_name as User_id.

Pending part - extracting text of all the files and then joining this text files with original csv file using User_id as their key.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import sys.process._
import java.net.URL
import java.io.File

object wikipedia{ 

def main(args: Array[String]) {  

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wiki").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)   
val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val input = sc.textFile("E:/new_data/resume.txt")

def fileDownloader(url: String, filename: String) = {
new URL(url) #> new File(filename) !!
}

input.foreach(x => {
// user_id is first part of the file 
// Url is the second part of the file.
  if (x.split(",")(1).isDefinedAt(12))
  { 
    //to get the extension of the document 
    val ex = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf('.'))

    // remove spaces from URL and replace with "%20"
    // storing the data file aftr giving the filename as user_id to particular location.
    fileDownloader(x.split(",")(1).replace(" ", "%20"), "E:/new_data/resume_list/"+x.split(",")(0)+ex)
  } } ) 

}
}
```

Comment: after downloading the file to my system, I extracted the Contents of resume to text. using apache Tika - Pdf parser, OOXML parser and Office parser. This concludes my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Scala function responsible for downloading content of URL. Example library that you can use for this is scalaj (https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http).

```
import scalaj.http._

def downloadURLContent(url: String): Array[Byte] = {
    val request = Http(url)
    val response = request.asBytes
    response.body
}
```

Then you can use this function with `RDD` or `Dataset` to download content for each URL using `map` transformation:

```
ds.map(r => downloadURLContent(r.Resume_file))
```

If you prefer using `DataFrame`, you just need to create `udf` based on `downloadURLContent` function and use `withColumn` transformation:

```
val downloadURLContentUDF = udf((url:String) => downloadURLContent(url))
df.withColumn("content", downloadURLContentUDF(df("Resume_file")))
```

Comment: thankyou for your revert.
But my spark -scala env is not recognizing and importing `scalaj.http._` I even tried adding library dependencies in my `build.sbt` -- but after I add The dependencies, it refuses to compile further.
my scala version - 2.10.4 and spark version  -- 2.0.1

Comment: Did you added dependency: `libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0"`?

Comment: If you can't add above dependency you can try one of approaches from this page: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-download-url-contents-to-string-file

Comment: Yes added the dependency but its throwong error : --> 
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalaj#scalaj-http;2.3.0: not found
[error] Could not create Eclipse project files:
[error] [Error evaluating task 'scalacOptions': error,Error evaluating task 'externalDependencyClasspath': error,Error evaluating task 'update': error,Error evaluating task 'updateClassifiers': error,Error evaluating task 'updateClassifiers': error]

Comment: Can you paste how you added this dependency? You might forget adding double %%.

Comment: yes, I am sorry, that was an error on my part, I tried the same format as my other dependencies.
However, I am still face some issue in the very last step: my output appears as : 
`[B@5a4c638d
[B@13e698c7
()`

for my input "81945bf4810c,21,http://che.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pdf-sample.pdf
6511bf3d46e4,22,http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"

Comment: I suppose you are printing your output using `toString` which for Scala `Array` returns result in format you showed.

Comment: `    val res = input.map(line => line.split(",")(2))    \\\\
    val data = res.map(x => downloadURLContent(x))     \\\\\
    data.take(1)   \\\\\
    println(data)} `